# 'this' not selecting on jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this

I have a function that is triggered when .btn is clicked, it will check if the input and text area with the class .req are filled or not. If not, its suppose to select only the empty elements and add a class   .warning. The conditional function is working well, but I can't select the elements using "this". Why? What's the right way?

```
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="./confirm.php">
            <table>
             <tr>
                <th>お名前*</th>
               <td>
                <input class="req" type="text" name="f_name" value="" placeholder="山田 太郎">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
        <textarea class="req" id="f_request" name="f_request" data-validation-engine="validate[required]"></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="btn">
            <input class="submit" type="hidden" name="input_flag" value="true">
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="お問い合わせ内容を確認">
        </div>
     </form>
     <script>   
        function check(){
                if(!$(".req").val()){
                    $('.submit').addClass('null');
                    console.log("null");
                } else{
                    $('.submit').removeClass('null');
                    console.log("normal");
                };
            };
            check();

        $('.btn').click(function(){
         check();
            if($('.req').val() != '') {
                $(this).removeClass('warning');

            }else{
                $(this).addClass('warning');
            }
         });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check all elements with `req` class, you can use `.each()` and `$(this)`

```
$('.btn').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    $('.req').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $(this).removeClass('warning');
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('warning');
        }
    });
});
```

Working snippet:-

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var emptyCounter = 0;
  $('.req').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != '') {
      $(this).removeClass('warning');
    }else{
      $(this).addClass('warning');
      emptyCounter++;
    }
  });
  if(emptyCounter > 0){
    $('.submit').addClass('null');
    console.log("null");
  } else{
    $('.submit').removeClass('null');
    console.log("normal");
  };
});
```

```css
.warning{
 border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="./confirm.php">
        <table>
         <tr>
            <th>お名前*</th>
           <td>
            <input class="req" type="text" name="f_name" value="" placeholder="山田 太郎">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
    <textarea class="req" id="f_request" name="f_request" data-validation-engine="validate[required]"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="btn">
        <input class="submit" type="hidden" name="input_flag" value="true">
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="お問い合わせ内容を確認">
    </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the value of the first element always instead of that check count of empty elements by using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method with a callback, which iterates and within callback `this` refers to the element.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    if($('.req').filter(function(){ return $(this).val() === ''; }).length === 0) {
        $(this).removeClass('warning');

    }else{
        $(this).addClass('warning');
    }
 });
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to apply style on the input then you can use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) method to iterate and [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass) method to toggle the class based on condition.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    // iterate over elements
    $('.req').each(function(){ 
      // toggle class based on value
      $(this).toggleClass('warning', this.value === '');
    });
 });
```

Comment: He want to apply style over `.req` element, not on button.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand , you have to loop through all `.req` and then check condition:

```
 $('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.req').each(function(index, elem) {
       if($(elem).val() != '') {
          $(elem).removeClass('warning');
       }else{
          $(elem).addClass('warning');
       }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If HTML code is something like that :

```
        <div>
        <input type="text" class="req" value=""/>
        <input type="text" class="req" value=""/>
        <input type="text" class="req" value=""/>
        <input type="text" class="req" value=""/>
        </div>
        Then you can check all elements with req class, you can use .each()

        $('.btn').click(function(){
           $('.req').each(function(){
             if($(this).val() != '') {
              $(this).removeClass('warning');
             }else{
              $(this).addClass('warning');
             }
           });
        });
```

***In your mentioned code $(this) targeting for .btn class not for input.***